# Need to check that user Login or not by using Browser Cache | Selenium Java

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, cookies, browser-cache, login-script

In my scenario, I've web page without any login panel. (i-e there's no account dashboard, usually other sites have at top right corner with user profile picture/name).

I've an email input field to enter email. And my page checks and shows a login button only if email is already registered in our database.
Then user logged in with his email and password, my page refreshes once with only some DOM changes and get user logged in to our system.

I'm running automation at 2 pages before this, but stucked here at 3rd page. I need to check this by browser cache/cookies because I havn't any other new element appeared at page.

Please help me. Is this possible to do? If not, then is there any other way to check this?

Thanks in advance to the responses.

I am using:
ChromeDriver 77.0.3865.40
Eclipse Version: 2019-06 (4.12.0) with Java

Comment: It is difficult to give you an answer to such a large question. First: When you only show the login-button when the email address is verified then you make it easy to "guess" valid addresses from your users. Then, you should hash the password (if you haven't already done it) and only send hashes to your database (never clear-text). Now I would suggest the Session to check the login. The session-id is stored in a cookie send with every request. The server then can read the information stored in the session (on the server) and determine the login-status. It can also "expire" automatically.

Comment: @GameDroids first of all very thanks.
I know question was too large, sorry for this.
I would try it through session now

Answer (score 0):

You don't need cookies in this case. Instead, you should property design your test case.

Before starting the browser, cookies should be cleared. Then you start your test, simulate normal login. Then navigate to the needed page. Now you know that the user was logged in and you know what to expect in your test.

Comment: Hi @mentallurg..
Already, this was a last option for me to clear cookies each time and simulate normal login.
But I was just thinking that if is it possible in some more intelligent way to behave differently for both already logged in or new login attempt.

BTW thanks for your reply.